1) "Six and a quarter of a mile" — Is this correct?; 2) "Six and a quarter of a million" — Is this correct?
As far as I understand, "a quarter of something" is correct.
But I'm interested in whether we can add a number to the beginning of this phrase or not.
For example, is "six and a quarter of something" correct?
my variants:
(1) six and a quarter of a mile — (I imply this means 6.25 miles)
(2) six and a quarter of a million — (I imply this means 6 250 000)
Is (1) correct?
Is (2) correct?
P.S.: I'm aware that instead (1) and (2) I can say:
(1a) six and a quarter miles — correct
(2a) six and a quarter million — correct

You're right as to the size of the numbers. But we don't say them in your first two suggested forms. Stick with (1a) and (2a).

If it's not clear why the second set is the right choice, consider the question "Six what?"

No they are not correct.
You should use the forms 1a and 2a.

And if there's three quarters, do the phrases "six and three quarters of a mile" and "six and three quarters of a million" become correct? Thanks.

no..........................
